# Why am I getting "Read access violation. _Right_data was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7" when calling a function of a parent class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, reference, access-violation

I have a class (A) that contains a list of objects of another class (B). In creating an object of class A, it makes a list of objects of class B and then calls a function of each of the B objects. Each B object stores a reference to the A object that created them. The aforementioned function returns the list of b objects by calling get_bs() on the B object's reference to object A. Depending on where in A's constructor I call the function on the B objects, the program either runs or gives an error, and I don't understand what's changing and why the error happens. Rubbish description I know but I don't know how better to word it.

I'm getting the error at runtime and it's pointing to a line in the included file vector which I don't really understand.

Here's the smallest code I could make that reproduced the error:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class A;

class B {
public:
    B(A &a) : m_a(a) {}
    ~B() {}
    void func();
    B &operator=(const B &b) { return *this; };
private:
    A &m_a;
};

class A {
public:
    A() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            m_temp_bs.push_back(B(*this));
            m_bs.push_back(&m_temp_bs[i]);
            m_bs[i]->func(); // fine
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            m_bs[i]->func(); // error ????
        }
    }
    ~A() {}
    std::vector<B*> get_bs() { return m_bs; }
private:
    std::vector<B> m_temp_bs = {};
    std::vector<B*> m_bs = {};
};

void B::func() {
    std::vector<B*> bs = m_a.get_bs();
}

int main() {
    A a = A();
}
```

Furthermore, when trying to shift things around, defining `B::func()` inline in the class definition, I get a different error at build: `Use of undefined type 'A'` which I also don't understand. I imagine the two errors are linked in some way.

Call Stack:

```
[External Code]
main() Line 40
A::A() Line 25
B::func() Line 36
A::get_bs() Line 28
std::vector<B *,std::allocator<B *>>::vector<B *,std::allocator<B *>>(const std::vector<B *,std::allocator<B *>> & _Right) Line 683     (This is in the vector file)
```

This is a snippet of said vector file where the error happened:

```cpp
#endif // _HAS_CXX23 && defined(__cpp_lib_concepts)

    _CONSTEXPR20 vector(const vector& _Right)
        : _Mypair(_One_then_variadic_args_t{}, _Alty_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(_Right._Getal())) {
        const auto& _Right_data = _Right._Mypair._Myval2;
        const auto _Count       = static_cast<size_type>(_Right_data._Mylast - _Right_data._Myfirst); // Exception thrown: read access violation.
        _Construct_n(_Count, _Right_data._Myfirst, _Right_data._Mylast); //                              _Right_data was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7.
    }
```

I hope the names A and B aren't too short to make the code difficult to read. I don't know what I'd call them otherwise.

I don't really know how to describe what my aim is without going into tons of detail about my original program which I don't think would be appropriate.

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps and sorry for the strange code - I'm pretty new to C++
Oh and I'm fairly new to Stack exchange as well so if I'm doing anything wrong with how I'm asking my question please tell me.

Comment: [`vector:push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) may invalidate pointers to existing elements (it invalidates when reallocation occurs)

Comment: You're storing pointers into `m_temp_bs`, and these become invalid when the vector gets reallocated as it grows. If you fix that, you will find that they also point into the original if you copy an `A`, and the copies become invalid when the original is destroyed.

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean by "they point into the original"?

Comment: If you copy an `A`, the pointers in the copy's `m_bs` are pointers to elements of the original's `m_temp_bs`, not to elements of its own copy of `m_temp_bs`.

Comment: Ah I see. That's fine because in my program I'd already given A it's own version of copying itself that happens to avoids that problem.

Comment: You can fix the first problem by `reserve`ing memory for the elements of `m_temp_bs` first, the second by adding a proper copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: I believe I fixed it now you've told me the problem - I looked up how to preallocate memory for the vector and now everything works. (Edit - I didn't see the previous comment while writing this)

Comment: Having a `std::vector<B>` should be totally fine since B is cheap to move (or copy). This should also have solved the issue. In current C++ if you can : avoid pointers. 
They may still be necessary if you need to call virtual functions on B in that case `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>` should also have been an option, since unique_ptr's are moveable they will still be valid after a vector resize

Answer (score 0):

@molbdnilo Pointed out to me that vectors reallocate memory when they get bigger, which invalidates the pointers stored in it. Turns out you can just preallocate memory for the vector and it works - I added `m_temp_bs.reserve(10);` to the start of A's constructor and it all works now.

Thanks all!